# How to run controller code after scope is compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a router which runs my controller when I go to url: `#/create`. I have configured it like so:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/create", {
        templateUrl: "templates/create",
        resolve: {
            form: function () {
                return { fields: [] };
            }
        },
        controller: "createController"
    })
```

And inside this controller I load some of my components asynchroniously inside my services and assign it to the respective scope property.

```
.controller(function ($scope, service /* other components */) {
    // code
    console.log($scope); // sometimes it gives $rootScope
    service.get().load([["forms"]], $scope); // the reaso I am passing the scope is that my service could assign loaded data to it
})
```

Sometimes when I refresh the page I have request for modules, but I do not have them assigned to the scope. After lots of debugging I have found out the problem. I am running into trouble when template is not compiled and instead of `$scope` I am getting `$rootScope`, so I get modules assigned to other/incorrect scope. The question here is, how can I run my controller code after the scope is compiled?

Answer (score 1):

You should never have $rootScope instead of the controller scope. I think something is not configured correctly. You should check that you :

- give a name to your controller (I don't see it in your example)
- don't have any ng-controller on your html code that could call the controller
- never try to create it directly in JS code

In another hand, you should not give $scope to your service. It is better to use callback instead.

You could change your controller accordingly :

```
/* resolve values should be inject */
.controller("createController", function ($scope, service, form) {
    $scope.form = form;

    service.get().load(function(value) {
        $scope.someValues = value;
    });
})
```

Comment: I both have name on my controller, html is ok and I am using promices in my service

Comment: Can you reproduce this into a plunker ? It will be better to find your issue. My opinion : You should find why $scope is $rootScope because it shouln't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a promise to resolve your data. When you call the server to get the data, it is a asynchronous operation.  Typically, the service returns a promise. You assign your data when the promise is resolved.

```
 service.get().success( function(data,status,headers){
       $scope.something = data;
 });
```